# Eclipse workspace issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a servlet that will help upload files from a html form.I am using apache commons fileUpload library.

The issue is when I upload a file, I get an Access Denied permission to write to a folder in the web content although i have granted permissions to all folders. Moreover, I have another project in the same workspace where a similar upload is being done to another folder and it executes.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Veera\VirtualClassroom\IP_Project1.1\WebContent\Videos\Kannada\Jodha Akbar (Access is denied.)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:205)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:157)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:426)
    at codes.UploadVideo.doPost(UploadVideo.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

Here's a code snippet.The doPost method

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))) {

        } else {
            try {
                ServletFileUpload in = new ServletFileUpload(
                        new DiskFileItemFactory());
                System.out.println("hello");
                String song_name = null, movie = null, category = null;
                List inp = in.parseRequest(request);
                Iterator it = inp.iterator();
                FileItem fi = null;
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    fi = (FileItem) it.next();
                    if (fi.isFormField()) {
                        if (fi.getFieldName().equals("song_name"))
                            song_name = fi.getString();
                        else if (fi.getFieldName().equals("film"))
                            movie = fi.getString();
                        else if (fi.getFieldName().equals("group"))
                            category = fi.getString();
                        System.out.println(song_name + movie + category);

                    } else {

                        String filename = fi.getName();

                        boolean status = new File(
                                "C:/Users/Veera/VirtualClassroom/IP_Project1.1/WebContent/Videos/"
                                        + category + "/" + movie).isDirectory();
                        System.out.println(status);
                        File fw = new File(
                                "C:/Users/Veera/VirtualClassroom/IP_Project1.1/WebContent/Videos/"
                                        + category + "/" + movie + "/"
                                        + filename);
                        fi.write(fw);

                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that one of the following is true:

- The path created for the file object does not represent a valid file. This might be because the `status` flag set to the return value of the `isDirectory()` method is being ignored.
- Related to the above, the path is constructed using the category and movie name, apart from the file name. Either of the parameters might be invalid or null, resulting in an incorrect path.

Correcting these would require verification that all fragments of your file path are valid, before attempting any creation of the file.

Comment: the form values are retrievable on servlet.I forgot to attach this console output last time. This is the message i got on console after java.io.exception

C:\Users\Veera\VirtualClassroom\IP_Project1.1\WebContent\Videos\Kannada\Jodha Akbar (Access is denied.)

Comment: Whether the values are retrievable is immaterial. The file's path ought to be valid at the time the file creation operation is attempted.

Comment: The folder is getting created but the write to that location
fi.write(fw) is where it throws exception saying that access is denied

Comment: thanks a lot! the reason for the error being i had two file buttons in the html page and one of which was sent empty,which would then try to create a file sent as null. "The access is denied" message put me on totally wrong track making me ponder if it was windows 7 issue.